# Problems adding animation

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to animate emission. Dope Sheet selected as editing context. But when i'm opening action editor - its empty. When inserting *Location, Rotation etc.* keyframes, they appear properly in action editor. Animation runs okay, but i can't save it. What i've missed?

Comment: Emission of what?

Comment: @lemon circled one. I actually was wrong. Emission strength. Here is the picture (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PoUQvq9dX5kazVLyRTrPqrxtfEhLqWmy/view?usp=sharing)
And here is .blend file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lF1tYl9CLDtqMQhIqOzahvnEIwiDK8RS/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emission channel is locked. Unlock it:

[image]

Comment: I'm really helpless with blender, maybe you can clarify. I need to export model and its animation into gltf format. When pressing RMB on my cube => insert keyframe => choosing one of the properties - animation beinig added both into action editor and under my model in _Scene Collection_ window. Link below.
Can i somehow transform changing emission strength keyframes into an animation as _Location, Scale, Rotation_ are?
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eYJaWkgo0aiGeg49DhrRwhlz4yeLEd3q/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In a gltf, I really don't know if its possible or not.

Comment: appreciated for your help, will find another way)

Comment: It seems material animation is not supported: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#animation

Comment: Can you give advice which technique to use to achieve similar effect but with animation?

Comment: A (bad) possibility: use another object nearly transparent so that it has several layers to mask the light. And animate it using shape keys so enable disable these layers.

Comment: Hey @lemon, I need to animate the emission strength on my object before exporting it to .glb as well, pretty much the same idea. Could you explain your "A (bad) possibility" a bit better please? I didn't get it, and I really want to try. Please